Footer flashes during route transition
The footer briefly flashes or collapses when switching routes, but only if the page is scrolled down to somewhere around the middle of a page. If I'm at the top of the page, the route transition works fine. This issue is more noticeable on high refresh rate monitors (e.g., 144-240+Hz). I'm not sure if this is a bug with the Nuxt layout or something else.
Here's the layout:
<template>
  <div>
    <AppHeader />

    <div>
      <slot />
    </div>

    <AppFooter />
  </div>
</template>

Reproduction:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-starter-upaovs?file=app%2Fapp.vue
Here's the video of the issue:
https://www.veed.io/view/44f8c82d-d7e9-408f-8056-1a256bea8c19?panel=share
Looking for a possible solution.

I can see someone wants to close this question for no reason. Here's what I say: it has a detailed explanation, it has a code example, it has a reproduction and I can also attach a video if it's necessary. StackOverFlow staff, please tell me what is the point of removing questions for fun? It meets all of the criteria for a valid question according to Stack Overflow's guidelines. Could you please provide clarification on why the question is going to  be closed or guide me on what further modifications?

A video/gif would really help to understand the problem, probably in slow motion. Also the question doesn't contain all relevant code. If it's specific to css transitions you have then please, provide them

First of all, there is no [SO] staff at this level. It's all community members. The more you help out, the more moderation rights you get. Secondly, the guidelines are open to interpretation and sometimes people are subjective. This is why, in the majority of cases, multiple closing votes are necessary to close a question. However, making accusations (e.g. "closing questions for fun") are not instrumental in your attempt to get help.  If anything, they tend to drive away anyone who might be willing to help. Be civil, patient, try not to get into or provoke arguments and you'll get the help.

@tao Sure, but my question is clear enough according to Stack Overflow's guidelines and my accusation of "closing questions for fun" totally makes sense, because there is no other reason to vote for closing it. If there is some issue you can always tell me and I will modify my question, but downvoting it for further closing demotivates people who is trying to learn. I posted a reproduction and kindly asked for a possible solution. If you need more details, I can link a video even in slow motion.

I've tried to re-create your problem and couldn't. I don't see any flashing. Also, the 32px font size doesn't help. I've also tried to observe the issue after changing the font size down to 12px. Again, all I see is the old content fading out, the new one faded in and the page being scrolled to top, which are all expected behavior, I believe. Would you be able to provide a video recording of the unwanted behavior?

@EstusFlask It's not the issue with css transitions. I removed transitions and I still see the footer flash. Besides, the reason I think it's related to Nuxt layout and particularly footer, because if I comment out the <AppFooter/>, I don't see the flash anymore. Everything I use in the reproduction corresponds the official nuxt/vue documentations.

@tao Sure, here you go, I uploaded it on VEED.IO - https://www.veed.io/view/44f8c82d-d7e9-408f-8056-1a256bea8c19?panel=share. You might not notice the issue if your monitor is 60hz. My monitor is 240hz and I see it, people who I sent this video see it too. You can try to record the video yourself in 240fps using bandicam or any alternative recorder and you'll notice it.

Ref: "my accusation totally makes sense". I did not say they don't make sense. I said they are not instrumental. They are not helping you get help. Ask yourself why you're here. If you're here to learn and get help, do not respond with aggression to anything, including what you might perceive as aggressive in other people's behavior. Please note this is a friendly advice, not an order. Feel free to do as you please and perhaps learn what I've just said empirically.

@tao I understand what you're trying to say, but after multiple questions being removed for the same reason, without asking me to modify the question or at least point on an issue, I can't stay silent. No aggression, I'm just trying to understand what's going on here.

Does .page-enter-active { min-height: 100vh; } help?

@tao No, it doesn't.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

The solution is recommended by @tao in the comments above.

When the fade out of the leaving page ends, the page element is removed and for a render cycle the footer is pushed up because there's
no page element. Once the new page is added, the footer naturally
moves down and the opacity transition begins. A simpler solution is
to not render the footer while the page is entering:

.content:has(.page-enter-active) + .footer {
    display: none;
}

Be sure to add class names to the footer and a content (wrapper div around <slot/>).
